# how to map a list of lists tsx

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, tsx

I am trying to structure a map of nested arrays within a map to a table using React in a TSX file. Currently, I am able to receive the data, but presently I am unable to fully map the interior arrays. Using a [0] only returns the first array, and using .map returns each column with all of the content of the array.

At present, I can only receive just the first array, or everything within the nested array in each column. The expected outcome is for each of the elements of each array to map into the table into individual columns per the correct associated header.

I have tried using the .flat within the map, but this still returns the entire array to each column

```
const headers = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']];
```

```
const bodyItems = [ 
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
['1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', 5a, '6a', '7a'],
['1b', '2b', '3b', '4b', '5b', '6b', '7b'],
['1c', '2c', '3c', '4c', '5c', '6c', '7c'],
['1d', '2d', '3d', '4d', '5d', '6d', '7d'],
['1e', '2e', '3e', '4e', '5e', '6e', '7e'],
['1f', '2f', '3f', '4f', '5f', '6f', '7f']
]
```

```
export const OutputDataTable = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container
                style={{
                    marginTop: '1rem'
                }}>
                <Table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {headers[0].map((title, index) =>
                                <th scope='col' key={index}>{title}</th>
                            )}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            {bodyItems.map((item, index) =>
                                <td scope='col' key={index}>{item[index]}</td>
                            )}
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default OutputDataTable;
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: `{bodyItems.map(row => <tr>{row.map(cell => <td>{cell}</td>)}</tr>)}` is a simplified version of what you need to do.